# unicode-math + mathtools: sin, cos etc in mathitalic

Tags: unicode-math, mathtools

Here it is my base file

```
$ cat test_00.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
%usepackage{unicode-math}
%usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\sin(00)$
\end{document}
$
```

and I have also the files `test_01.tex`, `test_10.tex` and `test_11.tex`, where I have

```
%usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
...$\sin(01)$

\usepackage{unicode-math}
%usepackage{mathtools}
...$\sin(10)$

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
...$\sin(11)$
```

respectively.  When I compile, with XeLaTeX, the files above I get the results shown in the image below — of course I'd like to know how to have an upright "sin" when I load both `unicode-math` and `mathtools`.

[image]

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and `amsmath`  should be loaded _always before_ `unicode-math`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should load `mathtools` before `unicode-math`, rather than after:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\( \sin(10) \)

\end{document}
```